# Show bundled messages once a week on a day other than Monday?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Google Inbox allows showing bundled messages either:

a) as they arrive,
 b) once a day at 7am, or
 c) once a week, on Monday at 7am.

Is there any way to get it to show the messages once a week, on SUNDAY at 7am?

Comment: Questions on applications or application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.